# The usage of 될 is not a word in my dictionary

Tags: word-usage

I'm studying Korean language by a book about korean radio news.

I ran into this sentence:

> 공영개발방식으로 짓게 **될** 신도시의

...of the new city **is a promising ** being built followed by public development policy ...

According to my electric dictionary,

1.될성-부르다

2.될성-싶다

Both of them mean 'there is a promising ...'.

The word of '될' is not in the indexes.

Something is omitted in this sentence?

Comment: 되다 (which primarily means "to become," but with -게, it can mean "to reach a certain situation or state") + [-ㄹ](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?nation=eng&ParaWordNo=69057) (which ends an adnominal phrase/clause and refers to a plan in your example) = 될.

Comment: Oh. my god-:-; This is a short of my search. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s “되” + “ㄹ”. In any verb that uses together with “을/ㄹ” is actually showing “plan”, “arrangement”, or “future tense”.

- 개발될 신도시 = city that is going develop
- 성공될 사람 = will become a successful person

Based on these two examples, it means that it’s a plan or future tense.

Comment: Hmm, 개발될 is fine but I don't think anyone says 성공될 - people will say 성공할.